# select.select() with regular files

Tags: python, select, file-io

Does anybody know if select.select() works with regular files or just with sockets/pipes?

I've tried on Solaris, Linux and Mac OS X - it doesn't block on select.select() call.

It just explodes my brain, trying something like this with no luck

```
import os
import select

fds = [ os.open("read.txt", os.O_RDONLY) ]

while True:
    reads, _, _ = select.select(fds, [], [], 2.0)
    if 0 < len(reads):
        print "-> ",os.read(reads[0], 10)
    else:
        print "timeout"
```

Comment: This has less to do with python than with the underlying operating system.  Better read up on non-blocking io and asynchronous io with regular files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html):

> Note that on Windows, it only works
>   for sockets; on other operating
>   systems, it also works for other file
>   types (in particular, on Unix, it
>   works on pipes). It cannot be used on
>   regular files to determine whether a
>   file has grown since it was last read.

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

`select` should work for files also, but I think FD for files gonna be always ready.

You should also check if you reached the end of the file. Here is an example which works for me:

```
import os
import select

fds = [ os.open("data", os.O_RDONLY) ]

while True:
    reads, _, _ = select.select(fds, [], [], 2.0)
    if 0 < len(reads):
        d = os.read(reads[0], 10)
        if d:
            print "-> ", d
        else:
            break
    else:
        print "timeout"
```